# Removing event handlers

Tags: c#, events, delegates

Is this:

```
Button.Click -= new EventHandler(Button_Click);
```

the same as this:

```
Button.Click -= Button_Click;
```

I ask because to me it seems that the former is removing a new reference to a method, and the latter one is removing a method itself. But then again, maybe the new EventHandler part is implicit in the += or -= overload in case the programmer doesn't explicitly assign it like that?

In case it is different how about

```
Button.Click -= new EventHandler(Button_Click);
```

VS

```
Button.Click -= Button_Click;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It is the same. The second is merely syntactic sugar for the first, and equality comparison is overloaded appropriately for delegate types:

> Two delegates of the same type with the same targets, methods, and invocation lists are considered equal.

Source: [MSDN, Delegate.Equality Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.op_equality.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The end result is the same.  The compiler is inferring the type of delegate automatically and as a result the new operator is not required to create it.