# How to add an event handler exactly once, if it doesn't exists

Tags: c#, .net, oop, events

I need to add and remove event handlers on my collection change:

```
public void SetStorageProviderFor<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expr, IStorageProvider sp) where T : class
{
    MemberExpression me = (MemberExpression)expr.Body;
    Set<T>().Local.CollectionChanged +=
        (sender, args) =>
        {
            foreach (var item in args.NewItems)
            {
                // get entity's property on member expression and set its value
            }
        }
}
```

1. How do i prevent adding the same handler?
2. How can i remove some specific handler? I don't think I should repeat all the same code but with "-=" mark...
   I also tried to make the handler an `Action` to store it in memory and let it be unassigned from `CollectionChanged` at any time:

   `Action<object, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs> act = 
       (sender, args) => { }`

but `CollectionChanged` cannot accept this Action as handler :(
Any help is appreciated.
**UPDATE**
My apologies, i shoud have posted more real code. The problem is that my handler is using more parameters than only of `CollectionChanged` and needs also `expr` and `sp` of the `SetStorageProviderFor` method. In this case I can create named method as Tim S. advices but if i provide it with additional params then i'll not be able to assign it to `Set<T>().Local.CollectionChanged` directly, will need anonymous lambda again ;(

Comment: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937181/c-sharp-pattern-to-prevent-an-event-handler-hooked-twice), [2.a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486214/c-sharp-removing-an-event-handler), [2.b](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307607/removing-event-handlers?lq=1)

Comment: You may want to try this `CollectionChangedEventHandler<object, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs> act = (sender, args) => { };` instead.

Comment: @KingKing just tried `Set<T>().Local.CollectionChanged += (NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler)act`, it says unable to cast

Comment: @KingKing "Delegate CollectionChangedEventHandler doesn't have type parameters"

Comment: @jim so what's the type of `Local`?

Comment: @KingKing Local is `System.CollectionObjectModel.ObservableCollection<T>`, and `Set' is Entity Framework entities set.

Comment: @jim What defines which previously-attached handlers should be removed, e.g. do you want to remove a previously-added handlers with the same `T`, or only with the same `T`, `expr`, and `sp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend that you keep something to match `T` to your last handler, such as a dictionary. I'm using a `static` dictionary, but if an instance one is what's needed, (so that it's the combination of this type and `T`, and not just statically `T`, that won't get more than one handler attached) change it to that.

In order to remove a handler from an event, you need to use `-=` and it needs to match the delegate that was first added. It [equates the delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.op_equality%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) using, among other things, the instance of the object that is created. This would be difficult to recreate due to the complexity of your lambda (and the classes/methods that are generated from it), so it's easier to store the old value in a way you can refer back to.

```
private static Dictionary<Type, NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler> handlers =
           new Dictionary<Type, NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler>();
public void SetStorageProviderFor<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expr,
                                     IStorageProvider sp) where T : class
{
    var local = Set<T>().Local;
    MemberExpression me = (MemberExpression)expr.Body;

    NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler existing;
    if (handlers.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out existing))
    {
        local.CollectionChanged -= existing;
    }

    NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler newHandler =
        (sender, args) =>
        {
            foreach (var item in args.NewItems)
            {
                // get entity's property on member expression and set its value
                // (uses expr and sp)
            }
        };
    local.CollectionChanged += newHandler;
    handlers[typeof(T)] = newHandler;
}
```

Comment: Tim, thank you. Please, take a look at updated post. I should have posted more real code...

Comment: Tim, thanks for wasting so much time for me. Will upvote and accept the answer, but now i wanna try totally another approach in my app (not because of this), and if it's unsuccessful, then will use your solution.