# 1 button, 2 webpages, but one webpage at a time?

Tags: c#, function, button

Here's what H have so far:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button3.BackgroundImage = slideshow_test.Properties.Resources.ai_yori_aoshi_5370;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    button3.BackgroundImage = slideshow_test.Properties.Resources.AiYoriAoshi_feature;
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    audio.Stop();
    if (button1.Enabled == true)
    {       
        timer1.Stop();
        pictureBox1.Visible = false;
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.watchcartoononline.com/anime/ai-yori-aoshi-guide");

         if (button2.Enabled == true)
         { 
             timer1.Stop();
             pictureBox1.Visible = false;
             System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.watchcartoononline.com/anime/ai-yori-aoshi-enishi-guide");
         }
    } 
}
```

this is only my test so far but what i want to do is change what button 3 does, i.e. if button 1 is clicked button three will open webpage 1, if button2 is clicked button 3 will open webpage 2, button 3's image will change depending, but what im finding with what i have done so far is that it opens BOTH pages AT THE SAME TIME ... how to i prevent this? i have tried if, else and else if, same result every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your buttons are enabled, you are checking to see if the buttons are enabled or disabled (clickable or not), not which one has been  clicked.

also:if (button2.Enabled == true)
is nested in the first conditional, I'm not sure if that's what you want.

You can: disable buttons 1 and 2 after their clicked so that, for instance button2.Enabled will now = false; (but then you will not be able to reclick that button)

More sophisticated, but better, is to use a delegate for the button3, and assign them in your button1_Click and button2_Click events. Something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button3.BackgroundImage = slideshow_test.Properties.Resources.ai_yori_aoshi_5370;
        button3.Click += new EventHandler(this.Button3_Click_First);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button3.BackgroundImage = slideshow_test.Properties.Resources.AiYoriAoshi_feature;
        button3.Click += new EventHandler(this.Button3_Click_Second);
    }

    void Button3_Click_First(Object sender,
                       EventArgs e)
    {
        // When the button is clicked,
        // change the button text, and disable it.

        timer1.Stop();
        pictureBox1.Visible = false;
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.watchcartoononline.com/anime/ai-yori-aoshi-guide");
    }

    void Button3_Click_Second(Object sender,
                       EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        pictureBox1.Visible = false;
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.watchcartoononline.com/anime/ai-yori-aoshi-enishi-guide");
    }
```

You may also have to check and make sure an event handler was not previously assigned, in calse someone clicks button1, then button2, then button1 ect. This is described here: [Removing event handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307607/removing-event-handlers)

Comment: thank you this worked perfectly, i can now have 10 buttons displayed , to show what they need to see , once one is clicked , the other 2 buttons open up for 1st and second series perfectly thank u

Answer (score 0):

You can handle your problem by storing the URL of the webpage in a private field, setting it when buttons 1 or 2 are clicked and reading from it after clicking button 3.

```
private string _address = null;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do other stuff
    _address = "http://www.watchcartoononline.com/anime/ai-yori-aoshi-guide";
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do other stuff
    _address = "http://www.watchcartoononline.com/anime/ai-yori-aoshi-enishi-guide";
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_address != null)
    {
        audio.Stop();
        if (button1.Enabled || button2.Enabled)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            pictureBox1.Visible = false;
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(_address);
        }
    }
}
```

I wasn't sure if all the code in `button3_Click` is necessary, so I cleared it up a little. I might be a bit off, though.

Answer (score 0):

button.Enabled is always true for all buttons by default unless you set it to false. So you cannot use button1.Enabled property to check which button is pressed. try below approach.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ViewState["Button1Clicked"] = true;
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ViewState["Button1Clicked"] = false;
}
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((bool)ViewState["Button1Clicked"])
    {
        //open webpage2 code comes here
    }
    else 
    {
        //open webpage2 code comes here
    }
}
```